# Android SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2a0b88

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting this error, when try to execute query below query- 
Also I am passing the values (uname,pass) from other java class. I tried to search the data in the table for both the values ie I am using both the parameters to search the data.

```
    public boolean validate(String uname, String pass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // SELECT
    String[] columns = { "_id" };

    // WHERE clause
    String selection = "user_name = ? AND _password";

    // WHERE clause arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = { uname, pass };

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return false;

}
```

Also, Please find the below logcat-

```
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:  bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2a0b88
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_bind_string(Native Method)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:241)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.bindString(SQLiteQuery.java:182)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:48)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
           01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
           01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
           01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
           01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):  at com.example.retailapp.Database.validate(Database.java:139)
           01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):  at com.example.retailapp.User.onClick(User.java:63)
           01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
          01-04 01:08:10.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1180):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing 2 arguments (uname, pass), but specify only a single placeholder ("?").

You probably wanted this:

```
// WHERE clause
String selection = "user_name = ? AND _password = ?";
```