# What is REGEXP alternative ? when using SQLCipher database?

Tags: regex, sqlcipher, android-database

My Android dictionary project use Arabic language for doing search view between search list. run project was successful with using regex. but using of SQLCipher for encrypt caused error. when typed Arabic character in search view:

> net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such function: REGEXP: while compiling: Select * From tblWord Where word_arabic REGEXP ‘^ل[ًٌٍَُِّْ]{0,}.*’

Now, Please tell me the way to use alternative for REGEXP.

Comment: in given example there is no need to use regexp and it can be replaced with `LIKE`. does it work for you?

Comment: cursor=mDatabase.rawQuery("Select * From tblWord Where " + language + " LIKE '_َ %' OR " + language + " LIKE '_ً %' OR " + language + " LIKE '_ُ %' OR " + language + " LIKE '_ٌ %' OR " + language + " LIKE '_ِ %' OR " + language + " LIKE '_ٍ %' ", args); /// // i did with this command and had this error :     net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: column index out of range: handle 0x52f75190

Comment: I see. how about `where substr(language, 1, 1) in ("ل", "[", "َ", "ً", "ُ", "ٌ", "ِ", "ٍ", "ّ", "ْ", "]", "{", "0")`?

Comment: as for 'column index out of range' [it maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759062/android-sqliteexception-bind-or-column-index-out-of-range-handle-0x2a0b88) if you specify something in `args` - since your SQL query has no placeholders to inject variables to.

Comment: Thanks @skyboy. but that Is not resolved .